# Transforming a tree structure from a list into a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I would like to transform a tree structure represented as a list like this...

```
['access_ctrl_allow',
 ['description', ['Access Control - Allow']],
 ['type', ['4']],
 ['metadata'],
 ['output', ['0']],
 ['rule',
  ['0',
   ['enabled', ['1']],
   ['action', ['type', ['accept_conn']]],
   ['match',
    ['services',
     ['0',
      ['name', ['DHCP']],
      ['trigger',
       ['0',
        ['protocol', ['17']],
        ['dst', ['start', ['67']], ['end', ['67']]],
        ['src', ['start', ['67']], ['end', ['68']]]]]]]]]]]
```

Into a Python dictionary, like this:

```
{'access_ctrl_allow': {'output': '0',
  'type': '4',
  'description': 'Access Control - Allow',
  'rule': {'0': {'action': {'type': 'accept_conn'},
    'enabled': '1',
    'match': {'services': {'0': {'trigger': {'0': {'src': {'start': '67',
          'end': '68'},
         'dst': {'start': '67', 'end': '67'},
         'protocol': '17'}},
       'name': 'DHCP'}}}}},
  'metadata': {}}}
```

I have code that does it and seems to produce correct output...

```
def dictify(data):
    k, v = data[0], data[1:]

    if len(v) == 0:
        return {k: {}}
    elif len(v) == 1 and len(v[0]) == 1:
        return {k: v[0][0]}
    else:
        new = {}
        for datum in v:
            new.update(dictify(datum))
        return {k: new}
```

...but it feels clunky.  Can you offer any suggestions for cleaning this up?  In particular, the need to dereference a list-in-a-list (`v[0][0]`) suggests to me that there must be a better way.

Comment: Use http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. This is not a programming question and SO is not for code reviews.

Comment: How is this not a programming question?  Is it only a programming question if I haven't already tried to solve it myself?  I can remove my code if it would make you happy.

Comment: There's no problem here to solve.  You said it yourself - this works for the input data and appears to be a perfectly reasonable recursive approach. It fits your data, and your expectations. Are you asking for a one-liner? What's wrong with it? Has it been identified as a bottleneck? Either way, it's not a great fit for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to accept slightly differnt output you can use `setdefault`:

```
import json
d={}
def rec(lst,d):
    for i in lst:
        if not isinstance(i,list):
            child=d.setdefault(i,{})
        else:
            rec(i,child)
rec(lst,d)
print json.dumps(d,indent=3)
```

**out:**

```
{
   "access_ctrl_allow": {
      "output": {
         "0": {}
      }, 
      "type": {
         "4": {}
      }, 
      "description": {
         "Access Control - Allow": {}
      }, 
      "rule": {
         "0": {
            "action": {
               "type": {
                  "accept_conn": {}
               }
            }, 
            "enabled": {
               "1": {}
            }, 
            "match": {
               "services": {
                  "0": {
                     "trigger": {
                        "0": {
                           "src": {
                              "start": {
                                 "67": {}
                              }, 
                              "end": {
                                 "68": {}
                              }
                           }, 
                           "dst": {
                              "start": {
                                 "67": {}
                              }, 
                              "end": {
                                 "67": {}
                              }
                           }, 
                           "protocol": {
                              "17": {}
                           }
                        }
                     }, 
                     "name": {
                        "DHCP": {}
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }, 
      "metadata": {}
   }
}
```

Comment: An earlier version of my code generated exactly this output, but I was unhappy with whole values-are-represented-as-keys result.  On the other hand, your code is lot shorter than mine was.  Thanks!